# Can't insert date in firebird using datetimepicker c#

Tags: c#, firebird2.5

I would like to ask for your help about my `datetimepicker`.
I can't insert date to my firebird database, my firebird version is `2.5.4`.
my `DATE` in firebird has datatype of `DATE`; I've also tried `TIMESTAMP`.

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FbConnection con = new FbConnection(BackEndCode.clKoneksyon.DbCon());
    FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO TBLLAN_SETUP (DATE) VALUES (@DATE)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", dtpDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString());

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
}
```

i also try this with no luck

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", dtpDate.Value.Date);
```

This is the error I got

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException' occurred in
>   FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll

EDIT: Updated code with exception handling

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    FbConnection con = new FbConnection(BackEndCode.clKoneksyon.DbCon());
    FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO TBLLAN_SETUP (DATE) VALUES (@DATE)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", dtpDate.Value.Date);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Dispose();
        con.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the error i  got
  Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code= -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 27
DATE

Comment: Is it allowed to execute INSERT INTO TBLLAN_SETUP (DATE) VALUES ('20150101') in your database at all?

Comment: it gives me error in database, i don't know what's wrong int DATE datatype in my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATE is a reserved word, so try:

```
"INSERT INTO TBLLAN_SETUP ([DATE]) VALUES (@DATE)"
```

Comment: Quoting of reserved words in Firebird is done with double quotes, so `"DATE"`.

Comment: thank you so much, i don't know that DATE is a reserved word. i change the name of my DATE and viola, it's working now :) thanks guys